# hazelcast client in vertx

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I have a 3.x vertx application running with a server and multiple clients. The server is set up to be a hazelcast cluster member and clients are hazelcast clients. I have to upgrade my app to vertx 4 where hazelcast clients are no longer supported - the ClientClusterProxy implementation doesn't support local members:

```
public Member getLocalMember() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Client has no local member!");
}
```

I tried to configure the clients as other cluster members, but then all my clients want to talk to each other, which is impossible in my case as the clients are often in different networks. So each time I start a new client it can't initialize.

Does anyone know why hazelcast clents are no longer supported in vertx ?

What is the best thing to do in my case?